# Twitter4j: User's profile URL is always null

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am trying to retrieve User's profile having a valid token. I am able to get the profile with all the info, but with no profile URL
Tried both

```
 User user = twitter.users().showUser(twitter.getId());
```

and

```
 User user = twitter.verifyCredentials();
```

Both requests work fine but return null when I call

```
user.getURL()
```

What can be a problem? Profile URL seems to be public information, I don't think am supposed to set any specific parameters or obtain permissions, provided I already have the token.
My Twitter4J version is 4.0.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `user.getURL()` does not return what you think.

According to documentation `user.getURL()` returns the URL that users provide in their profile. Not the URL of the user account.

You can check this documentation's URL section for more info: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/user

If you need to generate an URL for the user profile you can try something like this:

```java
User user = twitter.users().showUser(twitter.getId());
String profileURL = "https://twitter.com/" + user.getScreenName()
```